# SAP HANA SQL | Count different projected values in the same column

Tags: sql, count, hana

I have the following query in SAP HANA. I projected a column that displays 02 results in millions of lines. I would like to count how many of this two results each DISTINCT ZCGNOTAL has.

Please help me.

```
SELECT ZCGINSTAL, 
       ZCGNOTAL, 
       "Latitude",
       CASE WHEN "Latitude" > '0' THEN 'ZERADA' ELSE 'COORDENADA' END AS COORD
FROM "CLB162585"."062021MOM"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, the OP wants to know, for every value of `ZCGNOTAL` how many records have a value of "ZERADA" and how many have a value of "COORDENADA" in the computed column `COORD`.

That can be computed by a simple multi-column `GROUP BY` and a `COUNT` aggregation "on-top" of the existing query:

```
WITH base_data as (
   SELECT   ZCGINSTAL
          , ZCGNOTAL 
          , "Latitude"
          , CASE 
              WHEN "Latitude" > '0' THEN 'ZERADA' 
              ELSE 'COORDENADA' 
            END AS     COORD
FROM 
     "CLB162585"."062021MOM")
SELECT
     ZCGNOTAL
   , COORD
   , COUNT(*) as COORD_CNT 
FROM 
   base_data
GROUP BY
     ZCGNOTAL
   , COORD
```

If desired, the query can be rewritten to not use a common-table expression (WITH CLAUSE) or a subquery, but for SAP HANA this is unlikely to yield better performance. HANA rewrites the query before optimisation anyway and resolving subqueries is part of that rewriting process.

Comment: How do you think that specifically in HANA won't it be better to union two filtered datasets with constant `COORD` instead of `GROUP BY` calculated column? In calculation views it shows better performance it general, but in pure SQL it sometimes work differently

Comment: Without data and tracing the actual query executions any performance discussion is just guessing. As calculation views are turned into the same query structure as SQL statements the baseline assumption is that there are no fundamental differences in the execution speed of two same queries.

Comment: Hello again, thanks! It worked!

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to understand why it worked. Logically you called my original query as something (1) then you simply called three columns (ZCGNOTAL, COORD and you counted everything with * (2). As you simply called COORD and not its two different results, shouldn't it count everything and not the distinct results?

Comment: Happy to extend the answer; but let's make a deal: you provide some test data for your question and the desired output. Then I take the same test data to explain how the solution works. Other than that, there are plenty of SQL tutorials online. ;-)